# How to copy npm dependency with webpack config

Tags: npm, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I have a vue chrome extension. I have installed bootstrap 4 as a dependency, but I'm not able to use it inside the generated dist folder of webpack. How I can copy my dependencies automatically before run the `npm run watch:dev` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how I usually add node packages to the distribution.

```js
const plugins = [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin(
    [
      { from: 'node_modules/../package.css', to: './dist/css/' },
    ],
  ),
];
```

Then add it as a web accessible resource in your `manifest.json`

```json
"web_accessible_resources": [
  "dist/js/package.css"
],
```

And then you should be able to access it within your HTML.

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/package.css"/>
```